# C# socket timeout

Tags: c#, sockets

Sorry if the question is simple. But is it the same if I use

```
socket.SetSocketOption (SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.SendTimeout, 1000);
```

instead of

```
socket.SendTimeout = 1000;
```

or, it's different?

Thanks.

Comment: they are same...becuase this function Sets the specified Socket option to the specified value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both the same since the `socket.SendTimeout = 1000;` will eventually call the `SetSocketOption` method.